# Sending Ctrl-Alt-Break from C#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, sendkeys, postmessage

I'm trying to send a Ctrl-Alt-Break sequence to an RDP ActiveX window in a WebBrowser control in order to make it fullscreen.

I've searched the internet and tried numerous ways to accomplish this (PostMessage, keybd_event, SendMessage), and have not succeeded.

I am pretty sure I did something wrong, so I'd really like some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found another way to do it, and I'll post it here for the ones who hit this question from Google in search for such solution.

What I did, is get the RDP ActiveX by id from the WebBrowser control, and set it's "Fullscreen" property to true:

```
HtmlElement rdpClient = myWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("MsRdpClient");
rdpClient.SetAttribute("Fullscreen", "true");
```